# URL issue while using cURL command

Tags: curl

I'm running into issue while using curl to consume a webservice. There is URL which works fine if we consume using Postman but fails when consumed via cURL.

URL in Postman, which works fine:

```
https://localhost/WebService/InvokeEventRule?EventRuleName=S3Copy&EventParams=
```

Below is the cURL command, which fails and gives an error as '*EventParams is not recognized as an internal or external command*'

```
curl -k -u testuser:Password0! --url https://localhost/WebService/InvokeEventRule?EventRuleName=S3Copy&EventParams=
```

Notice the ampersand (&) after S3Copy in URL, if I replace it with ?, cURL will not give the error as mentioned above but the I'll get a 'Bad Request' and of course replacing `& with ?` will fail in Postman too.

Could anybody advise why CURL is not accepting ampersand (&) but ? and anyway it's failing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the url with quotes

`curl --request GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls?state=open&sort=updated'`

NOTE: If you are using postman you can get the curl request sample by clicking on the `code` option in postman. It will generate your code in most of the programming language.

[image]

Comment: Your kind help is very very much appreciated. Your solution has worked for me, many thanks!

Comment: Please don't use `--request GET` when it would already use GET...

Comment: I believe GET is required, because when not used, I get an error as curl: no URL specified!

Comment: For the above question, I generated the code from the postman. Actually you can use without a request 
`curl -X GET 'https://api.github.com/repos/facebook/react/pulls?state=open&sort=updated'`